# Does Realm automatically download all synced Realms?

Tags: android, realm

Let's say I have a Realm containing 50 custom objects on my server. If I sync to this Realm on a new client, will the entire Realm be downloaded from the server?

For some context, one feature of the app I'm developing is a chat platform, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to store the associated conversations and messages. Ideally I'd like to have one Realm for all conversations, where the only conversations that would be synced down to the user's device are ones that involve that user.

Answer (score 1):

Realm won't download *all* synced Realms, only the ones you explicitly open. However, the contents of each synced Realm you open will be downloaded in their entirety.

The ability to retrieve only a subset of objects within a synced Realm is a feature we hope to build out in the future.